# Jsoup text "subtraction" in a div containing a's

Tags: java, jsoup

Using jsoup, I know how to extract the text of an entire div:

```
<div class="c">
<a href="/relurl.php?refid=7">First Anchor Text</a>
 Something in Between 
 <a href="/john.doe?refid=7">Second Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

Such that `div.text()` yields:

> First Anchor Text Something in Between
>   Second Anchor Text

And I know how to extract the text of each anchor separately, such that the first `a.text()` yields:

> First Anchor Text

But is there an elegant way in Jsoup to extract *only* `Something in Between`?

(I can of course extract the 2 `a.text()` and "subtract" them from `div.text()` but I don't consider this elegant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Element#ownText()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29). Here's an extract from the linked javadoc:

> #### ownText
>
> ```
> public String ownText()
> ```
>
> Gets the text owned by this element only; does not get the combined text of all children.
>
> For example, given HTML `<p>Hello <b>there</b> now!</p>`, `p.ownText()` returns `"Hello now!"`, whereas `p.text()` returns `"Hello there now!"`. Note that the text within the `b` element is not returned, as it is not a direct child of the `p` element.

So, this should do:

```
String ownText = div.ownText();
// ...
```

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks++. Will accept in 9 minutes...

Comment: BTW, what happens when there are **two** "own text" inside that single div (separated by those `a` tags)?

Comment: All the own text will be returned. So if you have multple "betweens", then they will all be returned. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Since I only learned about `Element#ownText()` now, I am trying to understand how it works. So I understand that all own texts will be returned as one concatenated string. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly as demonstrated in the documentation.